# Match a pattern but capture a only a part of it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of text (from Wikipedia), and I need to scan it for citations, which may take any of the following three forms:

```
<ref name="somename" />
<ref name='somename' />
<ref name=somename />
```

What I've got so far is this:

```
var matches = text.match( /<ref name=["|']?(.*)["|']? \/>/gi );
```

And in a way, it works: it returns an array with the three citations. The problem is that what I want to capture are the NAMES inside the citations, not the citations themselves. I thought that by using those parenthesis in the regexp I was going to capture the names, but it looks like it doesn't work like that. Aren't they called capturing parenthesis?? How do I match the citations, but capture the names? Many thanks in advance!

Update: my code isn't working yet, so I'm pasting some of the context to see if someone can help me see where I'm going wrong... thanks again!

```
var text = this.getTextFromTextarea();

//First look for all the citations
var citations = [];
var citationsRegExp = /<ref name=["|']?([^"']*)["|']? \/>/gi;
var matches = text.match( citationsRegExp );

//Then create an object for each citation and store it for later
for ( var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++ ) {
    var citation = new Object();
    citation.string = matches[ i ];
    citation.name = citationsRegExp.exec( citation.string )[1];
    citations.push( citation );
}
```

The error, according to the console, is "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null", which I've tracked down to the line that says `citation.name = citationsRegExp.exec( citation.string )[1];` In other words, `exec` is returning null, which only happens when there isn't a match.

The text taken from the textarea is exactly this:

```
<ref name="somename" />
<ref name='somename' />
<ref name=somename />
```

The strangest part is that the for loop runs fine the first time, but on the second run it fails! I thought it had to do with the single quotes of the second citation, but then I tried changing their order and still the loop fails on the second run!

Comment: Why not use DOM manipulation?

Comment: The text is not part of the DOM, it comes from inside a textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7hCD/4/).  Since you want to match these strings globally, you'll have to loop through every match.  Let me know if you have any questions:

```
var citations = [],
    citationsRegExp = /<ref name=["|']?([^"']*)["|']? \/>/gi,
    text = $( 'textarea' ).val();

// Loop through every set of matches globally
while (matches = citationsRegExp.exec(text))
{
    // Add object to array
    citations.push({
        string : matches[0], // entire match
        name   : matches[1]  // first match group
    });
}

console.log( citations );
// Array[3]
//   0: Object
//     name: somename
//     string: <ref name="somename" />
//   1: Object
//     name: somename
//     string: <ref name='somename' />
//   2: Object
//     name: somename
//     string: <ref name=somename />
```

---

**Old answer**

[`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will only match the whole RegEx, so you will need to use [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to get the array containing the match groups.

```
var regex = /<ref name=["|']?([^"']*)["|']? \/>/i;
var matches = regex.exec("<ref name=somename />");

console.log(matches[1]);
// somename
```

Note: I also changed your matching group to `[^"']*` so that it wouldn't include the optional trailing `'` or `"`. Slightly modified code in action at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xv8hY/).

Comment: Is the downvote for not using the DOM?  I just answered the OP's question, but yes..this is a task for DOM manipulation not regular expressions.

Comment: I just found out that JavaScript regexes have a thing against single quotes... how would you adapt your regex? I tried escaping them like this: `/<ref name=["|\']?([^"\']*)["|\']? \/>/i` but didn't work!

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape a single quote.  Do you have an example of your code that you can update your question with?  The JSFiddle using JavaScript was working fine and `'` is not a reserved character as far as I know.

Comment: Beautiful, beautiful!! What a great way to start a day, waking up and finding a perfect answer to a bug that's been bugging me for hours! I'd give you +10 if I could, but I can't, so I upvote all your comments. Thanks one more time!